# Composition of $C^ i$ functions

Tags: calculus, continuity, function-and-relation-composition

It is clear that the composition of two $C^i$ function is still a $C^i$. But my question is more about a kind of its reciprocal.

Let's consider two open interval $I_1$ and $I_2$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Then we have a function
$g: I_1 \rightarrow I_2$ that is $C^{i+1}$, bijective and his derivate is non-zero in a point $x_0$ 
and $f: I_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is $C^i$ but not $C^{i+1}$ in $y_0:=g(x_0) \in I_2$.

My question is, can the composition function $f \circ g$ be $C^{i+1}$?
Or can a find a function $g$ that "erase" the $C^{i+1}$-discontinuity for every such fuction $f$?